# concurrent access to git repository

Tags: git, git-svn

There is a git repository which is updated from svn (`git svn fetch`) in fixed periods of time (1 hour for example). After fetch is finished every branch from `refs/heads` is updated with its corresponding branch from `refs/remotes`. Svn branches in `refs/heads` are only updated during this update process and nobody else has write access to them.

I wonder if it is possible to corrupt repository accessing it during svn update process? For example cloning whole repository, fetching from it latest changes or pushing (not to svn branches).

Comment: You mean concurrent operations? Like while you're pushing it a simultaneous fetch happens or some other combination of commands?

Comment: When you run "git svn fetch" it doesn't touch refs/heads/* (except the case of initial fetch which sets 'master'). So pushing at the same time as "git svn fetch" is safe. But updating refs/heads/* to refs/remotes/* is not safe if you push the same branches to that git repository at the same time because push modifies refs/heads/*.

Answer (score 1):

Based on personal experience, my company use SVN repository as major repository and new revisions produce to SVN repository every 20 minutes.

When run `git-svn` command, it will remember the last revision at the script that the `git-svn` beginning to run. For Example, if there are new revision produce to the svn repository, the new revision will not be fetch to the Git repository. it will fetch to the git repository on the next time you run `git svn fetch` command.

The most problem I face are that, I turn off the laptop which the `git svn fetch` still running but I won't notice about it because it is background process in the task scheduler. So, in this case, it may have lock file in the git repository. if the lock file happened, it will not be able to run `git svn fetch` until you delete the lock file in the git repository as the error message may show up.